# How can I return integers in string format in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to make a simple method like this:

```
def name(self):
    n = str(self.count)
    self.count += 1
    return n
```

Unfortunately, 'str' modifies double digit numbers into separate strings, one for each digit. How can I keep double digit numbers as single strings?

EDIT:

You can see below the output. I've included a lot of print statements.

```
f to be updated:  8
a after update:  {'2', '6', '8', '4'}
a:  {'2', '6', '8', '4'}
dom:  {'2': '0', '6': '0', '4': '1', '8': '5'}
cod:  {'2': '1', '6': '5', '4': '3', '8': '7'}
Key:  2
Key:  6
Key:  4
Key:  8
Key:  2
Key:  6
Key:  4
Key:  8
Dom:  {'5', '1', '0'}
Cod:  {'5', '1', '3', '7'}
s:  t
y:  9
o:  {'1', '5', '3', '7', '9'}
e:  10
f to be updated:  10
a after update:  {'1', '6', '4', '0', '2', '8'}
a:  {'1', '6', '4', '0', '2', '8'}
dom:  {'2': '0', '6': '0', '4': '1', '10': '0', '8': '5'}
cod:  {'2': '1', '6': '5', '4': '3', '10': '9', '8': '7'}
s:  t
```

You will see that 'f to be updated' is the name of a string to be added to the set 'a'. In each iteration, it occurs as it should; yet upon arriving at the double digit ten, the program puts two one digit numbers in instead.

Comment: What do you mean by " 'str' modifies double digit numbers into separate strings, on for each digit"?

Comment: Can you give an example of the output that occurs when running the code?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here. str() does not separate the two numbers of a double digit number. Also, in your function you have a statement after the return statement, for what purpose is that?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
global count 
count = 0
def n():
    global count
    return str(count)
    count += 1

test_val = n()
print(type(test_val))
```